# 2 select boxes with same id's but one hidden

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I've 2 select boxes with same id's as well as names but at a time only one is shown.

But when form is posted i do not get the exact value.It only displays the first value from the dropdown.

Following is a sample code of the same.

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST)
 ?>  



<form method="POST" action="">
    <select name="test" id="test">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

        <select name="test" id="test" style="display:none" >
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

I even tried surrounding the select box with a div and then hidding it.

Comment: Id should be `unique`  ->http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp

Comment: I wonder how this question deserve 2 up-votes ?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you have two select's with the same name, but when you hide one you also need to disable it too (`disabled="disabled"`).

As per HTML specification, disabled fields are not submitted so you should have your true value posted from the select that isn't disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're using some javascript to switch which select is displayed?

If that's the case, then start off with

```
<select name="test" id="test"></select>
<select name="test_dummy" id="test_dummy" style="display:none" ></select>
```

And whichever code changes the style attribute will also have to change the name and id attributes

Answer (score 1):

Even when one of these is hidden at every point, they should have different names in the markup so you can identify which one is which.

Otherwise it'll pass only the last element's (in the markup) value through the form (no matter if it's hidden via CSS or not).

I'm not quite sure why your hiding/showing only one of these at a time anyway. It'd likely be better if you replaced the `<option>`'s inside the select to the new ones, instead of using show/hide.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have different id's and in your code conditionally check which select box value is visible fetch it's value.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form, the POST data contains data basing on the attribute `name`. If they have the same name, the value of the second select **overwrites** the value chosen from the first one. Even if you hide it in the page.

If you want to have just the value of the first select, you should disable the second one, by adding `disabled="disabled"` or by changing its name.